# Centering a view within it's superview with Masonry

Tags: ios, masonry-ios-osx

I am trying to use `Masonry` for iOS. I have a label and a view.

I want to add the label to the view and center it horizontally in the view.

However the constraint I create with masonry does not work correctly.

```
UILabel *a = [UILabel new];
a.text = @"Hi";
a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[a sizeToFit];

UIView *b = [UIView new];
b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(a.frame) + 18.0f, 19.0f);
[b addSubview:a];

[a mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.centerX.equalTo(b.mas_centerX);
}];
```

How to center a view within it's "superview" correctly with Masonry?

Comment: Your code works for me, can you explain what does not work on your side? If the view has to be inside its superview, calling `make.centerX` will not be enough, to also position it vertically inside the view call `make.center.equalTo(b)`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I only want to center horizontally. To me when I use that constraint (in my example) the subview does not show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you add a top constraint:

```
[a mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(@0)
    make.centerX.equalTo(b);
}];
```

However you could auto-layout all the way and get rid of setting the `frame` and `sizeToFit` stuff:

```
UILabel *a = [UILabel new];
a.text = @"Hi";
a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIView *b = [UIView new];
[b addSubview:a];

[a mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(@0);
    make.centerX.equalTo(b);
}];

[b mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.width.equalTo(a).with.offset(18)
    make.height.equalTo(a)
}];
```